# Log4j A combination of DailyRollingFileAppender and RollingFileAppender

Tags: java, log4j, rollingfileappender

I need to split log files by file size like RollingFileAppender but I also want separate logs by date like DailyRollingFileAppender. I searched the web and can't find any good solution.

Is it possible to combine both of these in one log4j properties configuration?

Comment: You'll probably need to write your own appender, unless you are lucky enough to convince someone to write it for you. How do you want the files to be named once they exceed the size limit for the same day?

Comment: i want log4j to creat a new log file at the beinning of everyday and with the file name such as : 13_05_2014.log.And if that log file exceeds the limit of file size then it will automatically creat the new one with file name 13_05_2014(1).log and this will be continuous to the end of that day.It seems i have to creat my own appender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might look at [TimeAndSizeRollingAppender](http://www.simonsite.org.uk/).